# Redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https, cpanel

I am using Wordpress and I have my site url set to `HTTPS://` but its still not picking up the SSL yet anything to do with `cPanel` on the same domain is.

I have tried using the following in my `.htaccess` but it gives me a redirect loop why?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.nz/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: You're probably getting a redirect loop because something else is redirecting HTTPS *back* to HTTP

Comment: You need to use `https://` in site and home URL of WP permalink settings also.